# What is the possiblity of getting rabies bitten by a street dog in Berlin?

Tags: animals, animal-behaviour, europe, dogs, germany

What is the possiblity of getting rabies bitten by a street dog in Berlin. By street dog I mean the dog of a homeless person. Is there a high chance of rabies from that. I must say that I didn't provoke the dog. I don't know what provoked it, it came all of a sudden from behind barked for 3-4sec and bit me.  I know Germany is rabies free. But I assume since it is a street dog. I am not sure if the vaccines were provided to the dog. In such a case what should I do. The doctor who I contacted said Germany is rabies free and refused to give me anti rabies vaccine. What should I do in such a case , I am unable to find another doctor, and I am not sure how do I go about finding another doctor here. I am very new to the place and language is huge problem.

Comment: As the doctor said, the country is rabies free, the dog is not a stray but owned by someone (even though that person does not have a home) who would notice if his dog is ill. Stop worrying. The doctor would have given you medication or advice where to get it if needed, he did not so you do not need it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it’s asking for medical advice beyond what a doctor would give

Comment: No one here will contradict the advice of a local doctor. It's been well over a decade since the last case of rabies in Germany, so the risk must be insignificant. Plus I was once involved in a situation with a rabid dog in India, where it was very obvious that the dog was ill. Voted to close.

Comment: There are various reasons I could have closed this. I ended up going with the duplicate. John - please read [ask] to see what is in scope and on topic here. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In answer to the question in your title, "What is the possiblity of getting rabies bitten by a street dog in Berlin?": the possibility is zero, since (as the doctor correctly told you) Germany is rabies-free. For more details on Germany's rabies-free status, you may wish to read the answers to [this question](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/q/17778/8887) and [this question](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/q/17767/8887).

In answer to your final question, "What should I do in such a case?": you should do nothing other than getting on with your life, since Germany is rabies-free.